# Angular 2 Component issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've been learning Angular2 for a short time now, everything was fine. I've recently tried to use Ionic 2 with Angular 2 but cannot seem to use the custom component i make within my files. I'm sure it's a simple mistake on my part, was wondering if anyone could tell me what i'm doing wrong.

I have a base @Component with selector of 'contact-form', it does nothing except create a form within a templateURL html file.

Within the file i wish to use this component i import the Component from ./path...

i then add directives: [Component i created]

At this point i get the error:

> if component is an angular component, verify it is part of this module
>
> if component is a web component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the @ngModule.schemas of this component.

I've never had this issue when using the quickstart application, just within ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup no longer works. In early versions of Angular 2, you would import the classes to be used in your host component's template and list them in a `Directives` array of the host component.

Now the setup is very different. Have another [look at the quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#root-component).

What you want to do is list the directive among the `declarations` array of the module that will use it:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CustomDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Once the directive (or component) is declared as belonging to (or imported into) an `NgModule`, Angular will know to look for it in templates. So you can just start to use your custom directive/component without having to import it into the host component.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, a udemy course i used had not been updated appropriately and used an older version of the angular 2 file. So when learning it worked but when i implemented it into ionic with he latest version this was the issue.